# CALayer addSublayer does not work in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c

I want to achieve an effect that can turn to red when a cell is clicked in `CollectionView`,so I use `CAlayer`,but it does not work. When I use `target-action` inside cell to achieve, it can work perfectly.
Here are the codes:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    videoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"videoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CALayer *testLayer = [[CALayer layer] init];
    testLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
    testLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [cell.layer addSublayer:testLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the cell's `contentView` to accomplish this. Also, remember cells are caches and so you can not use state that you store inside a cell. You have to store it somewhere else. And you should not use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to update the UI. Rather change the state there and then request and update of the relevant cell.

Here is a nice example to illustrate. In this example you can select multiple cells and they all will have a red background. The selection state of a cell is stored inside a dictionary in the controller. You could easily change this if you e.g. only want to have a single cell selected at a given moment in time. Then you need to also updated the cell that became unselected but that is another example.

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"

@interface CollectionViewController () < UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource >

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary * selectedCells; // Key is integer row, value is boolean selected

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

    // Empty / nothing selected for now
    self.selectedCells = NSMutableDictionary.dictionary;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Configure the cell based on state
    if ( [( NSNumber * )[self.selectedCells objectForKey:@( indexPath.row )] boolValue] ) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    } else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
    }
    
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Flip selected state
    [self.selectedCells setObject:@( ! [( NSNumber * )[self.selectedCells objectForKey:@( indexPath.row )] boolValue] )
                   forKey:@( indexPath.row )];

    // Request an UI update to reflect the updated state
    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The operation about UI should be done in function cellForItemAtIndexPath, or it won't be effective even if I request an UI update using reload function, because the collectionview delegate will be recalculated after I use reload function

Comment: @全网最菜严同学 Yes exactly. The UI stuff all happens in ```cellForItemAtIndexPath``` and you request that to be updated after the state changed, here in the ```didSelect...``` message. But just to clarify the sequence. Tapping the cell causes ```didSelect...``` which updates the state and then requests an UI update of the relevant cell. The update is scheduled and when it happens (later) it will use the ```cellForItem...``` message to get a fresh cell.